# Enabling DockbarX

Tags: ubuntu, dock

I installed DockbarX on ubuntu 10.04 using following command:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dockbar-main/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install dockbarx
```

but dockbar is not showing up, do i have to do something to enable it.

**EDIT**

I want Dock to replace the whole panel.

Currently I am getting this look,
[image: This is what I have now]

but i want this kind of look
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what you're aiming at. Are you trying to make DockbarX bigger, change the theme, or make it full panel width?

Comment: @digitxp : I want to make it full panel width, as in windows 7.

Comment: Ah, I see. Go to `System -> Preferences -> DockbarX Preferences` (could be administration, I forget) and start tweaking with the settings there.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the GNOME panel where you want to add it and choose "Add to Panel", and there should be "DockbarX Applet" on the list. Or isn't it there?

Comment: It is there but it add Dock over the panel. I want Dock to replace the whole panel.Currently i am getting [link]this(http://bayimg.com/FaDOEAaDK) look  but i want [LINK]this http://bayimg.com/fadofAAdK kind of look

Comment: It's called DockBar because it's a Dock you add to a pre-existing Bar. You could use a different dock program (Cairo Dock or whatever), or just create a new Gnome Panel (uncheck 'Expand' in its properties, perhaps?) and add it to that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want same look as in your second picture you need a new version of DockbarX.The DockbarX ppa is only up to date for ubuntu 10.10. For 10.4, check out webupd8 ppa.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install dockbarx dockbarx-themes-extra

Other than that, you simply need to resize your panel and change its background. That's all that's been done in the screenshot you show. It's not a separate dock.